# VUE 3 Component Uncaught ReferenceError on update:modelValue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I catch error "Uncaught ReferenceError: comp1 is not defined" when make emit "update:modelValue" from component.

And it **NOT** happens in **dev**, only when I build.

**Parent:**

```
<script setup>
import TestComp from "/src/components/TestComp.vue";
</script>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      comp1: null // If remove this row - error will stop, but watcher don`t work ofcourse
    };
  },
  components: {
    TestComp
  },
  watch: {
    comp1(n, o) { console.log(o, n) },
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <TestComp
    v-model="comp1"
    class="form-control"
  />
</template>
```

**Component:**

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return { input: '' }
  }
});
</script>

<template>
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="input"
      @change="$emit('update:modelValue', input)"
    />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the TestComp import to the second `<script></script>`, and remove the first `<script setup></script>`

And your **Parent** page should be like this:

```html
<script>
import TestComp from '/src/components/TestComp.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      comp1: null, // If remove this row - error will stop, but watcher don`t work ofcourse
    }
  },
  components: {
    TestComp,
  },
  watch: {
    comp1(n, o) {
      console.log(o, n)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <TestComp v-model="comp1" class="form-control" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In child component you should use `value` attribute and `@input` event to mimic the `v-model` directive, and define `modelValue` as prop:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
   props:{
    modelValue:String
  }
});
</script>
<template>
    <input
      type="text"
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', input)"
    />
</template>
```